# Is there a way to parameterize cloud formation resource names?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to make AutoScalingGroup names on cloud formation templates dynamic. I was thinking if this is possible via parameters, or any other way?

```
"DynamicASGName": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties": {
      ...properties here...
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CloudFormation uses two sets of names: the *logical resource name*, to identify a resource within the stack, and the *physical name* which uniquely identifies it across the whole region.

CloudFormation doesn't support setting the logical name dynamically, but with certain types, you can set the physical name in the template with the [Name property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-name.html). For example:

```yaml
  MyUserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      UserPoolId: !Ref MyUserPool
      ClientName: !Sub '${AppName}-userpoolclient'
      GenerateSecret: false
```

Unfortunately, `AutoScalingGroup` doesn't support this.

A better solution is probably to use Tags on your resources.  Most AWS resource types (including `AutoScalingGroup`) support Tags and they can be set dynamically in a CloudFormation template.