# How to write my cloud formation more reusable instead of renaming resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I am new to cloudformation and I am writing some cfn code for the infrastructure of my project. But there is an issue that bugs me all the time when I am writing code. Let's say I have the following resources to create:

```
Resources: 
MyEC2Instance: 
  Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
  Properties: 
    ImageId: "ami-79fd7eee"
    KeyName: "testkey"
    BlockDeviceMappings: 
      - DeviceName: "/dev/sdm"
        Ebs: 
          VolumeType: "io1"
          Iops: "200"
          DeleteOnTermination: "false"
          VolumeSize: "20"
      - DeviceName: "/dev/sdk"
        NoDevice: {}
```

As you see I am creating a resource called MyEC2Instance. Now lets say I have another environment called stg which is the exact same as above so an easy way is to use the above code with a different stack name but I have been told that I need to rename my resource name as follows:

```
Resources: 
MyEC2InstanceStg1: 
  Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
  Properties: 
    ImageId: "ami-79fd7eee"
    KeyName: "testkey"
    BlockDeviceMappings: 
      - DeviceName: "/dev/sdm"
        Ebs: 
          VolumeType: "io1"
          Iops: "200"
          DeleteOnTermination: "false"
          VolumeSize: "20"
      - DeviceName: "/dev/sdk"
        NoDevice: {}
```

But to me this does not look professional since if I have 10 environments does this mean that I need to replicate my code 10 times and just rename the resources. Is there any better way for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to parameterize cloud formation resource names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854949/is-there-a-way-to-parameterize-cloud-formation-resource-names)

Comment: @Kannaiyan thanks but I di no think this will fully cover this issue since it does not mention if we use name property then what happens if we update the resources with the same logical resource name? does the mapping still take in place correctly?

Comment: Do different environments have the same set of resources, just with different names?

Comment: @JamieStarke my worrieness is at this part : MyEC2InstanceStg1 if I do not change this does mappiing btw resource and logical id happens correctly? specially for the case of update

Comment: On my team, we have a Dev, Staging and Production setup, and a single CloudFormation Template that is shared by all three, and separate stacks are created for each. All Logical IDs are the same, but the generated Physical IDs are different.

Comment: @JamieStarke Thanks I really appreciate your comment which made me to think more about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way we handle this on my team is we have a single shared Template that is used to generate stacks for each of our environments: `dev`, `staging` and `production`. The Logical IDs between each of the environments will be identical, but the generated Physical IDs will be different.

The one caveot on this is that if you have the different environments stacks in the same account, you have to ensure that any `Name` properties are unique. If they aren't required, don't set them, and CloudFormation will generate them for you. In the case that they are required I find `{"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-SomeName"}` to be helpful for this, as it makes each of the physical resources names relative to their environment stack. For example, with CodeBuild, a Project name is required, so we do something like:

```
Resources:
  Project:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-SlackBotLambda"
      ...
```

So if I'm on my `dev` stack, this makes the CodeBuild project named `dev-SlackBotLambda`.

Another strategy that we employ is passing in an `EnvironmentName` Parameter, so that we can have resources that are created on one environment and not on another. For example, I usually want to have build artifacts that are created in Dev and then shared with Staging and Production, so I have buckets that are created like this:

```
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - staging
      - production

  Conditions:
    ShouldGenerateArtifactBucket: !Equals [!Ref EnvironemntName, dev]

  Resources:
    ArtifactBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Condition: ShouldGenerateArtifactBucket
```

As long as your Stack Names are unique enough, you could even employ the first strategy with the second to make a bucket that will have a predictable enough name that one stack could reference the bucket artifact from the first.

Comment: So this means that I can have the same code for all my environment but then in properties of each resources I choose different name  to make them unique? right?

Comment: Correct. For most services, if you don't specify a name, then CloudFormation will assign a name to it based on the stack, and a random value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

Let me try and expand the situation to get a better understanding. In terms of a cloud deployment 10 resources are nothing. Even if you would manage to give your resources a cool unique name, it wouldn't help much when trying to manage those high number resources.

Also, logical names are sensitive and limited to characters and length, and because of that you will soon find out that you can't name them properly enough to achieve what you need. When you work with a small amount of resources, that kind makes sense, but in due time, resources tend to expand because it's so easy to do so.

As @jamie-starke suggested, you need to find other ways to help you track those resources. In my team we use lot's of template parameters, to drive what the stack should do. This is how we try to help track resources, as long as values are correctly though out. This is important because we recently had to rename tag values to make sure there was not overlap during search. For example we had names like `Fe-Multi`,`FEMulti-BESingle` and `FEMulti-BESingle-BEMulti`. When search for `FE-Multi` all three values were a hit because the console does a `StartsWith` conditional filtering.

- When possible build up a name for the resource using e.g. `!Sub "${AWS::StackName}-SlackBotLambda"` or `!Join` or other equivelants.
- When possible we annotate the resource with tags while always providing a Name tag.

We name the resources in the template in manner that helps the template be more readable. Often some logical names show up in the aws console because they don't accept names or tags and this is something we currently accept. For the rest of the resources, the names are mostly decorative. Resource names are also sensitive and limited to characters and length and therefore they can't get that expressive. For this reason, we've chosen to manage resources primarily through tags. Tags don't have restrictions and they offer an implicit language for querying.

With the understanding that CloudFormation templates are kind of awkward and that ultimately they depend on the rest of the AWS resources, some fragments of code need to be replicated and experimented especially when using conditions. If you need more information about this process let me know.

Because we don't want to replicate tag assignment to every resource we make sure that correct tags are provided during stack creation. To avoid any mistakes, we don't expect people to initialize a stack from the console but only from a PowerShell script that has full control of what is important.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer